# Share image with caption on whatsapp in ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have tried about share image/text on WhatsApp. so i am able to share image or text on WhatsApp successfully, but now i want to share the image with a caption on WhatsUpApplication, so I am unable to do this in swift4
so now i am searching for know how i can share image with caption on WhatsUpApplication in IOS application.

I have try with **UIActivityViewController** but it's not working with image and text and i read about **UIDocumentInteractionController** but there is no option for share both and i also implement Url Schema for WhatsApp but it's give only text sharing, not for both.

Please help me and don't make it duplicate because i didn't get any solution for it. maybe it's a issue of ios 11

Comment: So you say you have successfully shared images on WhatsApp. You should post your existing code, along with links on the resources you used. Did you find documentation on WhatsApp's APIs? Did you find a framework to use? Tell us about what you've learned and done so far.

Comment: are you asking for only image?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to share both image and text together on Whatsapp. It is a limitation of Whatsapp under iOS, it is nothing related to iOS11.

You can send an image or a text at a time, sharing both image and text together is not handled from the Whatsapp side.

Still, let's hope WhatsApp creates a proper iOS extension to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is there is any other way to do this.like facebook sharing.

Comment: Seems, currently no! As per the following WhatsApp faq link https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013, from iOS8 the proper way to share text/media is `UIActivityViewController `, Currently it can't share them both!

Comment: Yes i have same issue with UIActivityViewController

Comment: is still not working image + text sharing in WhatsApp ??